# Swift 3 Search Table from url

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have set up a table which populates by requesting json data from my server.

I am wanting to implement a search bar at the top which filters results based on the string from the search textbox.

I have approached this using the 'editing changed' action from the text box and calling the 'getdata()' function each time a key is pressed.

The problem I am experiencing is particularly noticeable on slower internet connections.

When a user types in a name there is a delay where the code is reloading the table 5-6 times while it executes the function for each letter. This looks confusing for the user.

Am I approaching this in the correct way? is there a way of cancelling any previous executions of the function each time a key is pressed?

```
@IBAction func textUpdated(_ sender: Any) {
    if (textField.text != nil){
        getdata(searchString: textField.text!)
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    print(value)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "vwTblCell2", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell2")
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    getdata(searchString: "")
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.tableData.count
}
// 3
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {
    let cell2: TblCell2 = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2") as! TblCell2
    cell2.nameLabel.text = "\(tableData[indexPath.row] as String)"+" "+"\(tableLastName[indexPath.row] as String)"
    cell2.companyLabel.text = tableCompany[indexPath.row]
    cell2.jobTitleLabel.text = tableJobTitle[indexPath.row]
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.****.co.uk/wellpleased/backend/profileimages/\(tableImage[indexPath.row])")
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        cell2.userImage.isHidden = true
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if data != nil {
            cell2.userImage?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                cell2.userImage.isHidden = false
            }
        }
    }
    return cell2
}
// 4
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Row \(tableID[indexPath.row]) selected")
    userSelect = tableID[indexPath.row]
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goSwipeScreen", sender: self)
    }
}
// 5
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 90
}
func getdata(searchString: String){
    let defaults = UserDefaults()
    let userid = defaults.string(forKey: "id")
    let newSearchString = searchString.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.asmserver.co.uk/wellpleased/backend/searchattendees.php?userid=\(userid!)&searchstring=\(newSearchString)&eventid=\(value as String)")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url as! URL) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let urlContent = data {
            do {
                if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: []) as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
                    self.tableData.removeAll()
                    self.tableLastName.removeAll()
                    self.tableCompany.removeAll()
                    self.tableJobTitle.removeAll()
                    self.tableImage.removeAll()
                    self.tableID.removeAll()
                    var i = 0
                    while i < jsonResult.count {
                        self.tableData.append(jsonResult[i]["firstname"]! as! String)
                         self.tableLastName.append(jsonResult[i]["lastname"]! as! String)
                        self.tableCompany.append(jsonResult[i]["company"]! as! String)
                        self.tableJobTitle.append(jsonResult[i]["jobtitle"]! as! String)
                        self.tableImage.append(jsonResult[i]["image"]! as! String)
                        self.tableID.append(jsonResult[i]["userid"]! as! String)
                        i = i + 1
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print("JSON serialization failed")
            }
        } else {
            print("ERROR FOUND HERE")
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
        self.tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: The big problem is that you are trying to populate the table asynchronously in `cellForRowAt`, and your approach is completely wrong.

Comment: Do you have an absolute need to query the server for each new search string ? Wouldn't it be a possibility to request once all data from the server and then search locally ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the initial state of your app is displaying all the available rows, then DON'T do the filtering on the server (by sending a new query for each change in the search field).

Use instead an UISearchBar and UISearchController as described [here](https://grokswift.com/swift-tableview-search-bar/) and in many other places to filter the local data only.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue in one of E-Commerce application then i did solve this way :

1. Decalare a global `searchTxt` variable
2. Store search string in textDidChange delegate and assign into `searchTxt`
3. Used Timer to invoke it after every 3 seconds
4. Called selector (searchUsingAPI) where i added all webservice code for fetching search results.

Here is the following code with method name :

```
   var debounceTimer: NSTimer?
    func test() {
        if let timer = debounceTimer {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
        debounceTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 0.3, target: self, selector: Selector("searchUsingAPI"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(debounceTimer!, forMode: "NSDefaultRunLoopMode")
    }
```

//MARK: WEBSERVICE METHODS

```
func searchUsingAPI() {

   //Web service fetching code goes here 
}
```

// MARK: - SEARCHBAR DELEGATES METHOD

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        self.searchText = searchText
        test()
        pageIndex           = 0
        pageSize            = 0
        TOTAL_PAGE_COUNT    = 0
    }
```

As Webservices were created such a way that only `10 Records` are fetched at a time using `Pagination` concept so here in `textDidChange` i also initialise `Pagination` related variables.

This is one of solution , may  be other too but i solved this way.
Hope this way you can solve your issue too. Feel free to comment if any.